# why linear regression gives high mean squared error with robust scaler?

Tags: regression, python, linear-model, robust

I've been trying to use a pipeline that consists of robust scaler and one of the algorithms like xgboost, ridge, lasso, and linear regression, and they all give better results except for linear regression that gives awfully higher error. I was wondering how this happens.